# SSH Bash using a TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, ssh, uwp

I'm developing a SSH client using UWP, and have got all the basics going. The issue I'm running into now is that if I run a command that outputs a carriage return without going to a new line (for a progress bar for example), the textblock doesn't replace the current line. It just creates a new one. So I would end up with an output such as:

```
Getting dependencies 5%

Getting dependencies 6%

Getting dependencies 7%

Getting dependencies 8%

Getting dependencies 9%

Getting dependencies 10%

Getting dependencies 11%
```

Instead of one line that updates itself. This is my xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stack">
        <TextBlock x:Name="oldconsole" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="console" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Scrollviewer>
```

and my c#:

```
//Called when I receive a new string
private async void WriteLine(string text)
{
    oldconsole.Text = oldconsole.Text + text;
    console.Text = "";
}
```

I've tried adding the following line at the beggining of `WriteLine()`:

```
if(text.StartsWith("\r") && !text.Contains("\n"))
    oldconsole.Text = oldconsole.Text.Remove(oldconsole.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

But as you've guessed, it completely messes up. How would I resolve this?

Comment: If you only need one line, why not just use `oldconsole.Text = text`?

Comment: Because I don't always only need one line. I don't want to get rid of all the text that occurs higher up, just the line that a linux terminal would be overwriting.